# Output of RandomSubSpace classifier Weka API in Java

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka

I've built a RandomSubSpace classifier in weka exploer and am now attemping to use it with the weka Java API, however, when I run distibutionForInstance() I am getting an array with 1.0 as the first value and 0.0 as all the rest. I am trying to get the numerical prediction not the class. Is there a different function I should be using or a different option on distributionForInstance? Code Snippet below:

Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("2015-09-6 Random Subspace Model.model");

Instances originalTrain = new DataSource("Instances.arff").getDataSet();

```
         int cIdx=originalTrain.numAttributes()-1;
         originalTrain.setClassIndex(cIdx);


         int s1=1;  


         double value=cls.classifyInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1));


         double[] percentage=cls.distributionForInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1));



         System.out.println("The predicted value of instance "+Integer.toString(s1) +"Value: " + percentage[1]); 
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(percentage));
```

This gives me output that looks like this:
The predicted value of instance 1Value: 0.0
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Does anyone know how to get the numerical output like I get in weka explorer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you classify an instance, we give you the index of the class attribute. You have to map, this value:

`originalTrain.classAttribute().value((int) cls.classifyInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1))))`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm stilling getting similar output. I keep getting "TX" as my output of this function for any instance I specify. I have no idea where that's coming from. States are part of the data set so I wonder if it's grabbing TX from there?

Comment: String value = originalTrain.classAttribute().value((int) cls.classifyInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1))))

Did you try to print this value?

Comment: Yes I did. I think the issue is that this model predicts a numerical value not a nominal one so there is no class membership. There should simply be a numerical prediction similar to the output of a linear regression model. Perhaps these are the wrong functions? They seem to all relate to class membership.

Comment: yes, the model predicts a double value, which represents the index of the class attribute value. When you get this value, you will get the predicated nominal class.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. However, I'm still a bit confused, to my understand if a classifier was built to predict a numerical independent value, there is no nominal class to be a member of. Every time I run  String percentage=originalTrain.classAttribute().value((int) cls.classifyInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1))); I get the same output which is the string "TX"

Comment: For example this is the output in weka explorer: inst#,    actual, predicted, error
     1      0.182      0.201      0.019

Comment: OK I think the issue is with setClassIndex()

Comment: Actually just figured it out. It was how I was setting the class index. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The method:

```
classif.distributionForInstance(instance);
```

returns a double array of probabilities of that instance membership for every different class. If you are getting a 1.0 on hte first element and 0.0 on the rest, it means the algorithm is pretty confident on predicting the first class for that particular instance. Other times, probabilities are distributed more evenly, when membership is not so clear.