# Java - Implementing Machine Learning methods on text mining

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I have some texts and i would like to mine these by implementing **Machine Learning** methods in Java using Weka libraries. For that purpose, i've already did something so far but since whole code is too long i just want to show some key methods and get an idea about how to train and test my dataset, and interpret results etc.

FYI, i am processing tweets with Twitter4J.

First, i fetched the tweets and saved in text file(of course in ARFF format). Then I manually labeled them regarding their sentiments(positive,neutral,negative). Based on selected classifier, i created test set from my training set thanks to **cross-validation**. Finally i classified them and print the summary and confusion matrix.

Here is one of my classifiers:  Naive Bayes code:

```
public static void ApplyNaiveBayes(Instances data) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Applying Naive Bayes \n");
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1); 
    StringToWordVector swv = new StringToWordVector();
    swv.setInputFormat(data);
    Instances dataFiltered = Filter.useFilter(data, swv);
    //System.out.println("Filtered data " +dataFiltered.toString());

    System.out.println("\n\nFiltered data:\n\n" + dataFiltered);

    Instances[][] split = crossValidationSplit(dataFiltered, 10);
    Instances[] trainingSets = split[0];
    Instances[] testingSets = split[1];


    NaiveBayes classifier = new NaiveBayes(); 

    FastVector predictions = new FastVector();


    classifier.buildClassifier(dataFiltered);
    System.out.println("\n\nClassifier model:\n\n" + classifier);     

    // Test the model
    for (int i = 0; i < trainingSets.length; i++) {
        classifier.buildClassifier(trainingSets[i]);
        // Test the model         
        Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(trainingSets[i]);
        eTest.evaluateModel(classifier, testingSets[i]);

        // Print the result to the Weka explorer:
        String strSummary = eTest.toSummaryString();
        System.out.println(strSummary);

        // Get the confusion matrix
        double[][] cmMatrix = eTest.confusionMatrix();
        for(int row_i=0; row_i<cmMatrix.length; row_i++){
            for(int col_i=0; col_i<cmMatrix.length; col_i++){
                System.out.print(cmMatrix[row_i][col_i]);
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And FYI, crossValidationSplit method is here:

```
    public static Instances[][] crossValidationSplit(Instances data, int     
    numberOfFolds) {
        Instances[][] split = new Instances[2][numberOfFolds];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFolds; i++) {
            split[0][i] = data.trainCV(numberOfFolds, i);
            split[1][i] = data.testCV(numberOfFolds, i);
        }

        return split;
    }
```

In the end, I've got 10 different results(because k=10). One of them is:

```
  Correctly Classified Instances           4               36.3636 %
  Incorrectly Classified Instances         7               63.6364 %
  Kappa statistic                          0.0723
  Mean absolute error                      0.427 
  Root mean squared error                  0.5922
  Relative absolute error                 93.4946 %
  Root relative squared error            116.5458 %
  Total Number of Instances               11     

  2.0|0.0|1.0|
  1.0|1.0|2.0|
  3.0|0.0|1.0|
```

So, how i can i interpret the results? Do you think i'm doing right about training and test sets? 
I want to obtain given text file's sentiment percent (positive,neutral,negative). How to infer my demand from these results?
Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately your code is a bit confused.

First of all, you train your model on the full set of your set:

```
classifier.buildClassifier(dataFiltered);
```

then you retrain your model inside your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < trainingSets.length; i++) {
    classifier.buildClassifier(trainingSets[i]);
    ...
 }
```

than you calculate the confusion mtx too. I think it is unnecessary.

In my opinion you need to apply `Evaluation.crossValidateModel()` method as the follows:
    
    `//set the class index
    dataFiltered.setClassIndex(dataFiltered.numAttributes() - 1);
    //build a model -- choose a classifier as you want
    classifier.buildClassifier(dataFiltered);
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataFiltered);
    eval.crossValidateModel(classifier, dataFiltered, 10, new Random(1));
    //print stats -- do not require to calculate confusion mtx, weka do it!
    System.out.println(classifier);
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
    System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString());
    System.out.println(eval.toClassDetailsString());`

Comment: Thanks for code, i obtained class details and class confusion matrix easily. However, i want to ask that if i am doing right? Because at the beginning, i labeled my dataset as positive,negative or neutral by hand. And finally i want to show accuracy of each classifier(other ones are KNN and C4.5) in Swing by graphically

Comment: It is depending on what you want. :) What is you goal? If you want to train an ML model, you need a manually labelled database. As you mentioned above, you did it, but I think a lot of labelled twitter database available, so I think it is unnecessary. On the other hand, to train an ML model, you required a larger data set.

Comment: Got it :) on the other hand, from the result                                                                                                        a     b  c   <-- classified as
 23  2 11 |  a = positive
 13  4  5 |  b = negative
 18  2 29 |  c = neutral ............     how can i get positive classified instances(or negative, neutral ) by programatically. Because i couldn't found any method related to it.

Comment: i was also wondering that the code you've posted is automatically separating training and test sets and doing classifications after this ? If yes, how? and in which portion it divide? if you could answer i appreciate that thanks :)

Comment: you can find the method to get the instance label at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534913/output-of-randomsubspace-classifier-weka-api-in-java/32544079#32544079

Comment: yes, it separate into test and train set. You can watch the source code of the method, and check how does it. ;)  it is similar as your method.

Answer (score 1):

You did some classification. Weka by default always takes the last column/attribute from your training dataset and tries to predict its value from all the other attributes. (Unless you tell it to use a different one).

Here, we can't tell if this is meaningful in your case. Probably not. (You don't show us any data).

Thus, the Naive-Bayes classification you performed would only be useful if the last column already contained a sentiment classifier with values positive,neutral,negative, created by some unsupervised learning method in a previous preprocessing step. Weka's classification algorithms do not infer this for you.

Now the result of what you did has nothing to do with sentiment analysis. I can't do this for you either.

By the way, You only have 11 instances. Why don't you classify them yourself?

Comment: So, how can i infer this result ? My data consist of tweets(string) and its sentiment which is written by hand. I have 100-200 tweets and in that example i used 10 cross-validation that's why it showed 11 instance. It can change.

Comment: It' complicated, and tweets are messy. I wanted to lookup up something but cannot find the link I was looking tor - Maybe, instead, this helps http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9458/nlp-opinion-mining-vs-sentiment-analysis/9464#9464